# How to check the keypress items found in list or not in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to check whether the pressed key items are found in my list or not. If it is found, then print it in a QLabel Text or print. Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication

class MyMenu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sample")
        self.list = ['W','Alt+K','Alt+R','Ctrl+Alt+A', 'Ctrl+P','Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Q']
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.key())
        if event.key() in self.list:
            print("Item Found in list")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyMenu()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? It seems like you are perhaps trying to reinvent [QShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html).

Comment: @ekhumoro, ;). More or less your assumption is correct.  I want to know some basic things, so I tried. store all my key sequences in a list and now I try to achieve it  through a keypress event

Comment: If you want details, the [QKeyEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html) gives you enough information to re-construct the strings in the list (i.e. via `event.key()`, `event.modifiers()` and `event.text()`).